# how to use parameter and stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

All what i am trying to do here is to set the Status field to "Complete" using stored procedure but for some reason it is not updating my table after i run the stored procedure.  can someone please help me here and tell what am i doing wrong?  thanks
//here is the stored proc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Update 
  @ID varchar 

AS 
BEGIN 
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from 
 -- interfering with SELECT statements. 
 SET NOCOUNT ON; 

 if exists (select Post_ID from  MyTable  WHERE Post_ID = @ID) 
  BEGIN 
        UPDATE MyTable 
        SET Status = 'Complete' 
        WHERE Post_ID = @ID 
  END 

END 

//and here is the code behind 
foreach (GridViewRow gr in GV_Action.Rows) 
        { 

                //string strID = gr.Cells[1].Text; 
                string ID = gr.Cells[1].Text; 
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString); 

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Update", con); 
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID; 

                cmd.Connection = con; 
                con.Open(); 
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                con.Close(); 

        }
```

Comment: Use SQL Profiler to see what is being executed on the server, and report back your findings.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you have ... is there no exception thrown?  Maybe try returning some value from the stored proc, for a sanity check.

Comment: no there is no exception thrown.. is there a way i can find out if the procedure run successfully?

Answer (score 0):

In the code "gr.Cells[1].Text" Cells[x] is zero based.  If the ID is in the very first column then you need 'gr.Cells[0].Text'.  Put a breakpoint on the very next line and see what value you have there.

Comment: "gr.Cells[1].Text" is the second column.

Comment: okay, i put a breakpoint as you suggested and my ID seems to be blank. is there a different way i can access the gridview value and assign it as string ID?  thanks

Comment: can i get help here?  what is the proper way of accessing a value in a gridview?  thanks